# C#: Hosting a Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I am done with writing windows service. What my service does is it calls another service and pull out some data from that service. Code is working fine as i checked it while debugging(Used attached to process option to debug the service).

Now i have to host the service on actual server. I can host the service using command InstallUtil.exe but my question is How this windows service will work on actual server? I know there is a OnStart() method but does that get called every second?I have no idea...

What i am expecting is my windows service should always call other service as written in code to check if it can download data if any from that service?

How can i achieve this? Please help!! Have i missed anything?

Comment: When wil the window service will call another service? on what condition?

Comment: OnStart is called every time windows service is started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OnStart` is only called when the windows service starts.

You should not do a lot inside this method since the operating system expects this call to return quickly (I think the default is 30 seconds or something like that).

What you want to do inside the `OnStart` method is to create a timer that runs every X seconds or minutes to do the actual work.

Another option is to start a new thread in this method (or a long running `Task`). Such thread or `Task` would actually have a loop and does the work that you need to do.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your explanation!!